# triggering an event every hour in android

Tags: java, android, unix

i am measuring through put TX and Rx in android thread. how i can put the Max through put in the database every hour. for example thread is calculating throughput every second and save it in the variable. As the hour passes it save the Max value in the data base table.

Answer (score 1):

Use system's [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) feature to set up recurring hourly event and, depending on your application design, your receiver should either tell the app to write data to the DB or do it by itself.